# How to specificaly sort a set depending on another set's elements?

Tags: flutter, dart

Let's say we have 2 Sets

```
void main() {
  Set set1 = {'mario', 'paper', 'is not bad'};
  
  Set set2 = {'paper', 'is not bad'};
  }
```

I am trying sort set1 by the order from set2 so that set1 can be

```
set1 = {'paper', 'is not bad', 'mario'};
```

edit: ok set is not necessary. A List can be used.

How would I do this?

Comment: You don't sort a `Set`. Sets don't have any concept of order, they store their objects in hash tables, not in a sequential list-like structure. If you need to be able to sort them, it's time to consider if you should even be using them rather than something like a `List`.

Comment: @Abion47 `Set` by default is a `LinkedHashSet`, which stores items in insertion order.

Comment: @jamesdlin That doesn't change the fact that you don't sort sets. If OP wants a sortable data structure, they should use a `List`. If they want a sortable _set_, they should explicitly use `LinkedHashSet` or `SplayTreeSet`.

Comment: is there a reason why set is not ideal to be used for this case? I can see clearly that sets are able to be sorted with these answers. I used sets in this case because the source contains repeating elements. But I think I could easily use Lists instead anyways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite simple actually if you approach from the most basic level, instead of relying on years / decades long usage of lists and comparators in everyday programming. Keep in mind that the order of union and intersection matters:

```
void main() {
    Set set1 = {'luigi', 'mario', 'paper', 'is not bad', 'coin', 'castle'};
    Set set2 = {'paper', 'is not bad', 'coin', 'luigi'};
    Set sortedSet = set2.union(set1).intersection(set1);
    sortedSet.forEach((element) => print(element));
}
```

--

EDIT (OP made a sub-question: how would he go about it he had Lists instead of Sets):

Like others have pointed out already - Set is a collection of well defined and distinct objects, List on the other hand can have duplicates and thus is not necessarily a Set(math), ergo union/intersect are no longer available.

Now that you are dealing with a List to begin with it makes sense "not to reinvent the wheel" and use the common List functions such as sort,compare,inverse.

But now we end up with a bunch of other cases. For example what if list1 has more elements than list2 plus some of those extra elements are repeated and not sorted. Bellow you will find 4 functions that deal with this differently:

```
void main() {

  /* fn1(); 
     * Probably what you are looking for #1.
     * All elements that are not present in list2 will appear at the end of list 1
     * also notice that those extra elements will be sorted as well in order of appearance in list1
     * [mario, luigi, luigi, mushroom, mushroom, castle]
  */
  void fn1() {
    List<String> list1 = ['luigi','mario','mushroom','luigi','castle','mushroom'];
    List<String> list2 = ['mario', 'luigi', 'coin'];

    List<String> list2Reveresed = list2.reversed.toList();
    list1.sort((a, b) => list1.indexOf(a).compareTo(list1.indexOf(b)));
    list1.sort((a, b) => list2Reveresed.indexOf(b).compareTo(list2.indexOf(a)));
    print(list1);
  }

  /* fn2(); 
     * Probably what you are looking for #2.
     * All elements that are not present in list2 will appear at the end of list 1
     * also notice that those extra elements will be sorted as well in alphabetical order
     * [mario, luigi, luigi, castle, mushroom, mushroom]
  */
  void fn2() {
    List<String> list1 = ['luigi','mario','mushroom','luigi','castle','mushroom'];
    List<String> list2 = ['mario', 'luigi', 'coin'];

    List<String> list2Reveresed = list2.reversed.toList();
    list1.sort();
    list1.sort((a, b) => list2Reveresed.indexOf(b).compareTo(list2.indexOf(a)));
    print(list1);
  }

  /* fn3()
     * Probably not what you are looking for.
     * All elements that are not present in list2 will appear at the end of list 1
     * also notice that those extra elements will not be sorted.
     * [mario, luigi, luigi, mushroom, castle, mushroom]
  */
    void fn3() {
    List<String> list1 = ['luigi','mario','mushroom','luigi','castle','mushroom'];
    List<String> list2 = ['mario', 'luigi', 'coin'];

    List<String> list2Reveresed = list2.reversed.toList();
    list1.sort((a, b) => list2Reveresed.indexOf(b).compareTo(list2.indexOf(a)));
    print(list1);
  }

  /* fn4() 
     * Least probable to be what you are looking for.
     * All elements that are not present in list2 will appear at the start of list 1,
     * also notice that those extra elements will not be sorted.
     * [mushroom, castle, mushroom, mario, luigi, luigi]
  */
  void fn4() {
    List<String> list1 = ['luigi','mario','mushroom','luigi','castle','mushroom'];
    List<String> list2 = ['mario', 'luigi', 'coin'];

    list1.sort((a, b) => list2.indexOf(a).compareTo(list2.indexOf(b)));
    print(list1);
  }

  fn1();
  fn2();
  fn3();
  fn4();
}
```

PS Before going into optimization you should always have a clear picture of what the end result should be. Also you should have an idea of how long these lists can possibly be, if they are going to be quite large then yes optimization should take place, but if they are going to be relatively short then optimization is a pure waste of dev time.

Comment: if this were a list, how would you approach it?

Comment: Edited my answer to cover what I'd do with lists. Didn't have enough info about what the end result you are expecting in edge cases , so you've got 4 different functions to choose from depending on your needs.

Comment: thanks, honestly for my use case, there are only 20 groups and you set example is the best and clearest for my needs. I'll keep using sets. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should convert set to list since a HashSet is unordered in Flutter, you can look up [this package](https://pub.dev/packages/ordered_set) tho for ordered sets. Here you go:

```
void main() {
  Set set1 = {'mario', 'paper', 'omg', 'is not bad', 'good'};
  
  Set set2 = {'paper', 'is not bad', 'omg'};

  var list1 = set1.toList();
  
  var list2 = set2.toList();
  
  
  var result = 
     list1.where((e) => list2.contains(e)).toList() // Get all common items
     ..sort((a, b) => list2.indexOf(a) - list2.indexOf(b)) // Sort common items based on list2 ordering
     ..addAll(list1.where((e) => !list2.contains(e))); // Add the rest of the items
  
  print(result); // [paper, is not bad, omg, mario, good]
}
```

Comment: That package uses a `SplayTreeSet` internally. If for whatever reason you absolutely need to use a set but also need to have it ordered, you might as well just use that.

Answer (score 0):

It's rather unusual to use `Set`s if you care about order, but if that's *really* what you want, you could:

1. Compute `set2.intersection(set1)` to find all items in both sets.  I believe that the resulting `Set` should preserve the order from `set2`.
2. Compute `set1.difference(set2)` to find all items in `set1` not in `set2`.
3. Append the result of step 2 to the result of step 1.

```dart
set1 = {...set2.intersection(set1), ...set1.difference(set2)};
```